# why isnt this script working? [JS]

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    spreadSheet= new Array(9),summary="";
    for(var i=0; i<spreadSheet.length; i++)
        spreadSheet[i]=0;

    document.writeln("<h1>Poll<\/h1><form method='get' id='tally' action=''>");
    document.writeln("<p>Enter Sales Amount:<br/><input type='text' id='cash'/><input type='button' value='calculate' onclick='calculateSalary()'/><\/p>");
    document.writeln("<\/form>");

    function calculateSalary(){
            var value=document.getElementById("cash").value;
            switch(value){
                case (value<300):++spreadSheet[0]; break;
                case (value<400):++spreadSheet[1]; break;
                case (value<500):++spreadSheet[2]; break;
                case (value<600):++spreadSheet[3]; break;
                case (value<700):++spreadSheet[4]; break;
                case (value<800):++spreadSheet[5]; break;
                case (value<900):++spreadSheet[6]; break;
                case (value<1000):++spreadSheet[7];break;
                default:++spreadSheet[8];break;
            }
    }
    function display(){
        summary="Number of People who earned salaries in the following ranges: \n\n";
        summary+="$200 – 299:\t" + spreadSheet[0] + "\n";
        summary+="$300 – 399:\t" + spreadSheet[1] + "\n";
        summary+="$400 – 499:\t" + spreadSheet[2] + "\n";
        summary+="$500 – 599:\t" + spreadSheet[3] + "\n";
        summary+="$600 – 699:\t" + spreadSheet[4] + "\n";
        summary+="$700 – 799:\t" + spreadSheet[5] + "\n";
        summary+="$800 – 899:\t" + spreadSheet[6] + "\n";
        summary+="$900 – 999:\t" + spreadSheet[7] + "\n";
        summary+="$1000 and over\t" + spreadSheet[8] + "\n";
        return summary;
    }
    document.writeln("<textarea cols='80' rows='15'>"+display()+"<\/textarea>");

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I am a javascript newbie, and yes, I honestly tried helping myself before posting.

I just want to make a simple program that takes in user input from a button, and then increments a global array element based off of the value the user inputs. The problem is I can't get the global array to work right. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: no error message in the log?

Comment: Why are you using `document.write()` from within the `<head>` section?  It should be in `<body>`.

Comment: please clarify "doesn't work"

Comment: @jfriend00 ... or replaced by something  else

Comment: The base problem is that you increase the `spreadSheet` variable but then do nothing with it. The page contents won't update automatically.

Comment: Also, if you're going to use that switch technique, it should be `switch( true )`.

Comment: No errors, it just doesn't do what i need it to do. For example, if i put in 500 then the array[3] index should go from 0 to 1. Nothing is happening when I press the "calculate" button and its because the values aren't being assigned to the global array

Comment: @JohnBudah The values *are* being assigned to the array, you're just not doing anything with them!

Comment: @Juhana - the `display()` function is called in the last `document.writeln()`.  The spreadsheet variable is used there.

Comment: So how can I make the textarea reload dynamically?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, when the page loads - but not when the user clicks the "calculate" button.

Comment: Why is it tagged [AJAX]?

Comment: @Juhana, jfriiend is right I called the display() function to output the array elements at the end

Comment: @JohnBudah Yes, at the end when the page loads. Not when the user clicks the button.

Comment: @JohnBudah but that only happens on page load, but never again later

Comment: Please avoid multiple comments. Consider going into a chat room.

Comment: @Haidro John Budah doesn't have enough reputation to chat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As established in the comments, the problem is that you increment the values but then do nothing with them. The textarea's contents have already been set and won't be automatically rebuilt when the variables that were originally used to build it change.

Give the textarea an id when creating it:

```
document.writeln("<textarea cols='80' rows='15' id='results'>"+display()+"<\/textarea>");
```

Add this to the `calculateSalary()` function so that it updates the textarea:

```
document.getElementById( 'results' ).value = display();
```

Also change the switch statement to `switch( true )` so that it increments the correct variable.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QkQ5v/